# Error LNK2005 in c program

Tags: c

When I tried to run the program, visual studio showed the errors `LNK2005` and `LNK1169`.

I created two source files and I use `#include` in main file. Could someone tell me why it is wrong

Here is my code in 1.5.3.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Print.cpp"

    int main()
{
    double b;
    printf("Input a number\n");
    scanf_s("%lf\n", &b);
    print(b);//call print()
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my code in Print.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void print(double a)
{
    double c = a * 2;
    printf("%lf multyply by 2 is %lf", a, c);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Including the error messages in your question may be of help.

Comment: So VS gave you only the text *Errors LNK2005 and LNK1169*? No other information? No text description, no line numbers, no code, absolutely **nothing** but *Errors LNK2005 and LNK1169*? I find that somewhat hard to believe. You have the error messages right on the screen in front of you; why aren't they in your post where we have that information as well?

Comment: Why the C tag when the files are `*.cpp`?

Comment: @Gordon: Do you not have a "Print.h" header file?

Comment: @WeatherVane: VS defaults all source files to `*.cpp`. You have to rename them if you want `.c` files.

Comment: @KenWhite: This is not an external library problem. This is a lack of a header include.

Comment: @Gordon: Don't post images of text; post the text itself

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: OK. It's still a VLQ post that fails to include the relevant details and is mistagged.

Comment: @KenWhite: Concur, except that I'm pretty sure the OP is attempting this in C, it's just that they don't know how to make VS behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
#include "Print.cpp"
```

This **defines** the function `void print(double a)` in both the `Print.cpp` file **AND** the `1.5.3.cpp` file.  When the `1.5.3.cpp` file is compiled it produces a symbol `void print(double a)` in the 1.5.3.obj file.  Similarly, when the `Print.cpp` file is compiled, it also produces a symbol `void print(double a)` in the Print.obj file.  Thus the linker errors:

> **LNK2005** "void __cdecl print(double)" (?print@@YAXN@Z) already defined in 1.5.3.obj
>   **LNK1169** one or more multiply defined symbols found

You need to **declare** `void print(double a)` in a `Print.h` file and `#include` it in the `1.5.3.cpp` and `Print.cpp` files.

You may want to see:
[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)